# Spring - react to changes to a remote Git on same server

Tags: java, spring, git

I want to be able to listen to changes like commits and if such an event happens execute further git operations directly by using Java.

Is there a way to do this via some framework? If yes, do I need to implement a "polling" strategy or is there a way to provide an interface so that Git can notify me about changes?

@Windle I will have an application server running spring project and server shall notice changes happen on the git server like a branch will be created or has been changed.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Like @Andronicus said in his answer, we really need some more details of what you are trying to do. The answer will vary wildly depending on which tools you have access to, what environment you're running in, etc.

Comment: I hope the additional explanation helps to understand what I am looking for. I don't have more details myself yet, because I am still thinking about the "how to".